# Is 'interdiction sur eux' correct?

Tags: prépositions, pronoms-personnels

In the case of a sentence like this: *'Il n'y a pas une interdiction sur eux. (le cannabis et l'alcool)'*, is it correct to use '*sur eux*'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can say “Ils ne sont pas interdits” instead.

*Sur* is not used together with *interdiction* except for the standard place indication as in *l'interdiction de jouer au ballon sur la plage*. As you can notice here as well, *de* can be used to specify the action which is forbidden. But there's no way you can complement *interdiction* with a concrete<sup>1</sup> object directly. You should rephrase as mentioned above.

Otherwise, in other contexts, *sur eux* is the appropriate way to combine *sur* and the third person plural pronoun, for both persons and other objects. For example: *Il n'y a pas d'ombre sur eux*.

—
<sup>1. It's possible for some abstract nouns, e.g. *interdiction de sortie*, *de vente*, *de stationnement*, etc., or with a definite article in an affirmative sentence, e.g. *l'interdiction du cannabis* (if using a pronoun, *son interdiction*).</sup>

Answer (score 3):

As alreay stated "*sur eux*" can't be used here but should you want to keep a similar structure, you might say:

> Il n'y a pas d'interdiction les concernant.

Answer (score -2):

Il n'y a pas d'interdiction:

- **contre eux**;
- **envers eux**;
- **pour eux**.  *pour* est neutre et fonctionne pour presque toutes les constructions.